# select from database 3 words (but only when the result = 3)

Tags: php, sql, database, select

```
 $alfabet = Array('a','b','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k');
 $letter= $alfabet[array_rand($alfabet)];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM kolom WHERE beginletter = '".$letter."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3" ;
```

I want to select 3 words from the database with a random beginletter.
It is possible that the result is only 2.
In that case i want to search for another random letter until i have 3 words with the same beginletter.

How can i do this?

Sietsko

Comment: @Sietsko..which RDMS you are using..??

Comment: Wrap it in a while loop until your condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

```
$okay = false;
while (!$okay) {
     $alfabet = Array('a','b','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k');
     $letter= $alfabet[array_rand($alfabet)];

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM kolom WHERE beginletter = '".$letter."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3" ;
     // ...do sql query and fetch results...
     $okay = count($resultlist)>=3;
}
```